# put Image into a div but still doesn't showed into it

Tags: html, header, photo

**My Code**

```css
.header {
  background-color: #694e4e;
  height: 95px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 300%;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: Verdana, Courier, monospace;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 24px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.douag {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>hhhh </h1>
  <img src="ss.png" class="douag" />
</div>
```

The problem is ss.png is located outside the header on the top of the page. I want it in it.

Comment: What do you want to do with the image?

Answer (score 0):

Below you can see image is appear.

```css
.header {
  background-color: #694e4e;
  height: 95px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 300%;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: Verdana, Courier, monospace;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 24px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.douag {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>hhhh </h1>
  <img src="https://bitcoin.org/img/icons/opengraph.png" class="douag" />
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t1vn4w1n

Answer (score 0):

This is because you h1 tag is a block element by default. Set you h1 tag to:

```
h1 {    
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

See [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/DollarChills/pen/GMXXjj) for an example.